# Googlemaps does not appears only black screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

i have made a typically googlemaps app. And it worked fine in about 2 months, but last night i wanted to added more functions and what happens is that googlemaps does not appears, only a black screen. My app does not spit any errors out and everything works except that googlemaps is replaced by a black screen. Why is this happening? Any ideas?

It works fine on the emulator, but not on my phone.

GoogleMaps Activity

```
public class GoogleMaps extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, BackGroundService.class);
    stopService(intent1);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlemaps);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvGoogleMaps);
    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);
    ourLocation();

    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_pointer);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    towers = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancel(uniqueID);
}
```

GoogleMaps layout

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mvGoogleMaps"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="My APY Key"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rememberforme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/round_pointer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rememberforme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.rememberforme.GoogleMaps" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.IkkeImplementeret.Situationer" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.IkkeImplementeret.Tid" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.rememberforme.Locations" >
        </activity>

        <service 
            android:name="com.example.rememberforme.BackGroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="LocationLoggerService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you sure you are using a correct api Key in: android:apiKey="My APY Key"

Comment: Is one of the recent additions the `Touchy` overlay?  If so, make sure it is not completely opaque.